# Значение конструкции с многоточием

Tags: java

Что означает `E...` в `public void addElement(E... data) { /* .... */ }` в Java?

Comment: видимо тип `E`, которых может быть передано неограниченное количество

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а многоточие на кой? :)

Comment: @teran именно указание на то, что их может быть передано любое количество

Comment: вы, разумеется , видели, как объявляется метод public static void main(String[] args) , так вот его же можно объявить так public static void main(String... args). По сути это одно и тоже для тела метода - вы получаете массив в данном случае стрингов , который называется args. Но для того, кто вызывает этот метод разница состоит в том, что в первом случае вы должны передать в качестве параметра именно массив, а во втором вы можете передать неограниченное количество аргументов просто через запятую, а не массив в чистом виде. Иногда это очень удобно. Вот это и есть многоточие

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Многоточие указывает на то, что может быть передано произвольное число аргументов указанного типа (см. [Varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)). В итоге внутри метода это преобразуется в массив и можно взять элемент по индексу даже.

Пример:

```
void foo(String... args) {        
    System.out.println(args[0]); // по индексу

    for (String arg : args) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}
```

Может быть вызвано вот так:

```
foo("foo"); // один
foo("foo", "bar"); // два
foo("foo", "bar", "lol"); // три
foo(new String[] { "foo", "bar" }); // даже массив
foo(); // без аргументов
```

---

Соответственно в вопросе тоже самое, только касается типа `E` - ожидается именно его поступление вовнутрь.