# Синтаксис Java. Что означает запись "String ... names"

Tags: java, core

Всем доброго времени суток. Пробую решать задачки на codewars, я начинающий, пожалуйста не судите строго. Не прошу решить а меня задачу, так как есть пару идей как реализовать её, но хочу спросить у уважаемого сообщества что означает запись `String ... name`? Используется вот в каком контексте:

```
public static String whoLikesIt(String ... name){
    //Some magic
return " "
}
```

Так же оставлю ссылку на задачу, может кому нужно будет
[Ссылка на задачу на сodewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5266876b8f4bf2da9b000362/train/java)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367398/what-is-the-ellipsis-for-in-this-method-signature

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что означает double... в java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/891050/), [Значение конструкции с многоточием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745798/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запись (String...names), переданная в качестве параметра, позволяет нам указать, что в метод передаётся  какое-то количество строк. Мы не оговариваем заранее, сколько их должно быть, поэтому работа метода становится более гибкой. Например:

```
public void sayHi(String...names) {
   for(String name : names) {
      System.out.println("Hello" + name);
}
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо)